# How can I boot a Chromebook Lenovo Yoga e11 that has a 'broken' eMMC?

Tags: boot, data-recovery, chrome-book, chrome-os

I have a chromebook that has a broken eMMC drive on the mother board. I removed the screw protection from it so there is no OS verification.

One problem is that I can't enter ChromeOS to enable boot from usb. I am stuck becase I cant recover the system because of the broken eMMC and I can't boot from sd or USB.

How can I somehow execute some script that will enable the BIOS boot or just boot Linux from USB?

Edit: logs when trying to restore system

- hardware_diagnostics.log https://pastebin.com/fWvvQK6e
- recovery.log https://pastebin.com/UrQ1QgkY
- dmesg https://pastebin.com/spMemWnV
- progress.log https://pastebin.com/0mGkFqDP
- spinner.log https://pastebin.com/2ucuCAJu

Comment: how do you expect to execute a script if you cannot boot? ... what does `tosted` mean? ... did you mean toasted?

Comment: your question is about booting a computer, so it is not a question about linux

Comment: Yes I meant burned / toasted. Yes its question about linux because chromeos is a linux bases operating system.

Answer (score 2):

I think this depends on the extent to which your internal eMMC drive is 'toasted'. If the chip that contains the boot firmware is completely fried, then the device is essentially an unusable plastic brick and at this point I would recommend disposal.

How do you know the chip is broken? What did you do to it? What happens when you try to boot the machine?

What I would try first is to see if you can recover the Chrome OS bootloader using the following guide:

[Recover your Chromebook](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en)

My understanding is that Chromebook internal storage chips include a ROM area that contains a backup of the boot firmware. So, unless the eMMC is physically damaged or has been flashed or corrupted somehow, recovery should be possible.

Otherwise, [this guide](https://libreboot.org/docs/install/c201.html) explains how you can flash a new boot firmware onto an ASUS Chromebook C201, using an external hardware flashing device. Your Chromebook is not the same model, so I don't know if this will work. It *may* do, if it uses the same CPU/mainboard setup as the C201, but it's risky. I would only recommend trying this as a last resort, if all else fails and you would otherwise throw the device away anyway.

Comment: Well i know eMMC have 100% bad blocks You can check it from hardware_diagnostics.log i cant enter command prompt because i am stuck in dev mode os ver. off. I cant recover system using usb or sd because recovery want to install system on eMMC if i could crossystem dev_boot_legacy=1 or dev_boot_default=usb that will be great.

Comment: @c64girl how are you able to check that log file, if you can't access a command prompt? What do you mean by 'stuck in dev mode'? What do you see on the screen when you try to boot the device?

Comment: When i try to do recovery using USB stick the logs files save on it those files are in first comment.

Comment: @c64girl What happens when you try to boot the machine, without any USB inserted?

Comment: Hey i fix the problem, i run the recovery mode and after 40 min it got restored to default chrome. But it was the black screnn all the time... LOL !